# Rating a user based on his score, load certain image if the score is between certain interval

Tags: php, mysql

I want to load a  rating image which depends on the users average score on some tests. 
For example If the users score is between 5(not including 5 ) and 6 (including 6), he should get image 6.png, which is a 3 star rating.

So far I tried this, but it doesnt work, it seems there is a mistake somewhere.

```
Rating: 
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] < 1): ?><img src='images/rating/0.png' hspace='3'   style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?> 
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] == 1): ?><img src='images/rating/1.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 1 && <= 2): ?><img src='images/rating/2.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 2 && <= 3): ?><img src='images/rating/3.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 3 && <= 4): ?><img src='images/rating/4.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 4 && <= 5): ?><img src='images/rating/5.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 5 && <= 6): ?><img src='images/rating/6.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 6 && <= 7): ?><img src='images/rating/7.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 7 && <= 8): ?><img src='images/rating/8.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 8 && <= 9): ?><img src='images/rating/9.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
<? if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 9 && <= 10): ?><img src='images/rating/10.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'><? endif;?>
```

any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers from the others are good to. But here is the real problem of your code:

You wrote:

```
if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 3 && <= 4)
```

but correct is:

```
if ($row['AVG(answer)'] > 3 && $row['AVG(answer)'] <= 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$row['AVG(answer)']` can only be 0 to 9 then why not just do

```
<img src='images/rating/<?php echo ceil($row['AVG(answer)']); ?>.png' hspace='3' style='vertical-align:middle;'>
```

Also, there may be a error in your query (should be doing something like `SELECT AVG(answer) as avg_answer ...` then echoing `$row['avg_answer']`

Comment: well, the avg answer could be 4,673, and we dont have a 4,67.png. we only have 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.png

Comment: So what do you want to happen if avg answer is over 10 /'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a ceil statement to make this much easier:

```
<?php
    echo "<img src='images/rating/".ceil($row['AVG(answer)']).".png' hspace='3'   style='vertical-align:middle;'>";
?>
```

This will work for all the data you have. No need for all those multiple if statements.

You only ever want things rounded up, so this will work just fine for all instances.